# aosp_x86-eng build on AOSP 4.3 source code is failing with error __strlen_chk

Tags: android

I am trying to build the x86 image on  AOSP 4.3 source code.
followed below steps:

- source build/envsetup.sh
- lunch ( selected  aosp_x86-eng)
- make -j4

It gives below error.

```
bionic/libc/include/string.h:219: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:219: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:219: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
bionic/libc/include/string.h:219: error: undefined reference to '__strlen_chk'
```

Question:

1. It the steps for building x86 in AOSP 4.3 is correct?
2. How we can fix the above error.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it when building libcurl. The key idea is setting `D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0` in flags to disable checks, as mentioned in the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-4.2_r1/libc/string/__strlen_chk.c).

Answer (score -1):

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libc

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this means, and how it answers the question.